# Bolt CMS - Fetching data from a newly created YAML file

Tags: php, bolt-cms

I have created a new file:

```
app/config/contacts.yml
```

with the contents:

```
email: 'email@domain.co.uk'
address: 'Planetary House'
address1: 'Planetary Road'
address2: 'address2'
address3: 'postcode'
phone: '0871 2007065'
phone2: '08000 328311'
company: '1234567'
vat: '123456677'
```

In my template file how would I fetch the contents of this newly created YAML file?

I know to use the method below for the existing config.yml etc.

```
app.config.get('general/sitename')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've added a new file that isn't in the standard set recognised by Bolt, you're not going to be able to do this out of the box without manually loading the file.

Option 1 is to parse and load the file into Bolt's config object. You can do this by putting the following code in your `index.php` or bootstrap file (before the call to `$app->run()`)

```
$path = $app['resources']->getPath('config');
$filename = $path . '/contacts.yml';
$parser = new Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser();
$yml = $parser->parse(file_get_contents($filename) . "\n");
$app['config']->set('contacts', $yml);
```

After doing this you can access it in your template using: `app.config.get('contacts')`

A second option if you don't mind using an existing file is to take advantage of the theme config.yml file which is loaded automatically from the same directory as your theme. You could just add your block to there eg:
    contacts:
        email: 'email@domain.co.uk'
        address: 'Planetary House'
        ....

And then this will be loaded into the `theme` variable and you can use in your template like: `{{ theme.contacts.email }}`